# How to change color of ticker value on condition basis like if I have value les than 0 then green otherwise red in OBIEE?

Tags: javascript, html, css, obiee

```
&nbsp;&nbsp;


<!-- np -->

<p style="font-size:15px; color:black; font-family:tahoma">

<span style="font-size:15px; color:#2A5240; font-family:tahoma; font-weight: bold">
Net Profit
</span>
<span style="font-size:15px; color:black; font-family:tahoma; font-weight: bold"">
for the year is
<span style="font-size:15px; color:#003F63; font-family:tahoma; font-weight: bold">
@4
</span>

|
<!-- ebitda -->


<span style="font-size:15px; color:#2A5240; font-family:tahoma; font-weight: bold">
EBITDA
</span>
<span style="font-size:15px; color:black; font-family:tahoma; font-weight: bold"">
for the year

is
<span style="font-size:15px; color:#003F63; font-family:tahoma; font-weight: bold">
@5
</span>

|
<!-- change in revenue -->



<span style="font-size:15px; color:#2A5240; font-family:tahoma; font-weight: bold">
Change in Revenue
</span>
<span style="font-size:15px; color:black; font-family:tahoma; font-weight: bold"">
for the year
</span>
is
<span style="font-size:15px; color:#003F63; font-family:tahoma; font-weight: bold">
@6
</span>
|

<!-- change in expenses -->


<span style="font-size:15px; color:#2A5240; font-family:tahoma; font-weight: bold">
Change in Expenses
</span>
<span style="font-size:15px; color:black; font-family:tahoma; font-weight: bold"">
for the year
is
<span style="font-size:15px; color:#003F63; font-family:tahoma; font-weight: bold">
@7
</span>

</p>**strong text**
```

Comment: the issue is not resolved.

Comment: I think you'll have to show us more - there is no way of telling from the HTML alone how values get changed and where it might be that a change in value might trigger change in styling. On the whole CSS cannot be set in relation to content, you'd have to use JS.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by A Haworth you're not providing a lot of information. No precise version for starters. I general he's spot on: you'd need to script that in JS and that's a very bad idea because the you'll have to verify this keeps working every time the solution is upgraded. You're referencing stuff that's out-of-the-box and can be changed by Oracle any time.